# What is the name of the place trophies go?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

My best guess is *trophy case* but I'm assuming I'm wrong.

Comment: Incorrect assumption. [_Trophy case_](http://www.trophycasesnow.com/) it is.

Comment: Mine go on the [mantelpiece](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mantelpiece), even though I don't have a mantelpiece. But then I don't have all that many trophies, either.

Comment: Or [_trophy shelf_](http://www.google.com/search?num=10&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1459&bih=736&q=on+the+trophy+shelf&oq=on+the+trophy+shelf&gs_l=img.3...1588.6125.0.7124.29.10.0.7.0.1.539.2754.1j0j7j1j0j1.10.0...0.0...1ac.1.uq_CZQwSNH8), if the trophies aren't enclosed in glass.

Answer (score 8):

In the UK it's invariably a **trophy cabinet**.

Comment: Posted as an answer not a comment because it appears there may be regional or dialectal differences.

Comment: I find *trophy cabinet* unambiguous, whereas the first thing I thought of for *trophy case* was some sort of soft slip-case to wrap and protect it. But I’m precaffeinated, so the analogy with *book case* didn’t come to mind at first.

Answer (score 2):

Saying *trophy case* is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to lock them up in a *display case*, a *pedestal* will do fine.

(a display case you dedicate to storing trophies becomes a trophy case...)

Answer (score 0):

a fancier option would be 'vitrine'

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Do you mind adding the definition of "vitrine" to your answer?